# Android - XMPP over websockets

Tags: android, websocket, xmpp

I am trying to implement a chat functionality in my android app using XMPP over WebSockets.

I was able to find a library (org.igniterealtime.smack), but the connection is established over TCP and not over WebSockets, which I don't want.

Does anybody had to implement the same functionality and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websocket support for Smack is tracked as [SMACK-835](https://igniterealtime.atlassian.net/browse/SMACK-835). It is currently in Smack's main branch and scheduled to become the Smack 4.5 release.

You can use it right now by consuming either Smack pre-releases or the nightly artifacts from https://www.igniterealtime.org/archiva/repository/maven/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's OK and doesn't violate TOS and whatnot but first sentence implies general guidance for XMPP + WebSocket and not strictly asking for Smack answer so - you could use JaXMPP library (https://github.com/tigase/jaxmpp), which already supports WebSocket and and is compatible with Android (StorkIM, https://github.com/tigase/stork is based on it).

It's quite easy to establish WebSocket connection (even encrypted):

```java
JID user = JID.jidInstance("user@example.com/resource");
String password = "password";

Jaxmpp contact = new Jaxmpp();
contact.getModulesManager().register(new MessageModule());

contact.getConnectionConfiguration().setConnectionType(ConnectionConfiguration.ConnectionType.websocket);
contact.getConnectionConfiguration().setBoshService("wss://xmpp.example.com:5291");

contact.getConnectionConfiguration().setUserJID(user.getBareJid());
contact.getConnectionConfiguration().setUserPassword(password);

try {
    contact.login(true);
    if (contact.isConnected()) {
        contact.disconnect();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(disclaimer: I'm from Tigase team, which created both JaXMPP and StorkIM)